# Angular list rendering

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller

I've recently started to use Angular for front-end development to communicate with an API to perform state changes in the UI. I would like to know what is the way to update a front-end component after an API call.

For example, I have a list which is generated through Angular ng-repeat after an API call. I also have a button to remove list items which uses ng-click. I would like to know what is the best way to update the front-end once this element is removed and the success function is called.

From what I can see, you can either re-render the list through an API call or remove the list item from the HTML list through Angular. Of course, re-rendering the whole list has more performance costs but is this the right way to make sure data is synchronized?

Comment: I'm sure if I understood fully your question. Just setting the new value to your $scope variable would not work? $scope.array = new_value;

Comment: If you're the only one to modify the list, just removing the item locally after you know the server removed it on the server can be sufficient and is more efficient. If the list is updated by several concurrent users or processes, or if the server might do additional changes linked to the deletion, you might want to refresh the list. It's not a technical problem, but a functional choice. I would refresh the list by default, and only start optmizing if really necessary.

Comment: With ng-repeat make sure you are using "track by" so that you aren't unnecessarily re-creating all the dom nodes when only one item was removed from the list. This gives you the ability to reload all the data but minimizes some of the performance costs of re-rendering the view. See the section on Tracking and Duplicates: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat